# Assertion failure in UITableView after registering nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I ‘m trying to make a table programmatically. But when it dequeues it throws “unable to dequeue a cell with identifier…” exception. I have a custom cell in a nib and I am registering it in `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
[self.myTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];
```

Later, while configuring the cell in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath` it crashes dequeueing on:

```
  CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This is the stacktrace:

> 2015-03-04 23:15:06.296 MyApp[6470:3127630] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.16.25/UITableView.m:6116 2015-03-04
>   23:15:06.299 MyApp[6470:3127630] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to
>   dequeue a cell with identifier MyCustomCell - must register a nib or a
>   class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x2249149f 0x2ff49c8b 0x22491375 0x23162d1f 0x25ab503d 0x1026d3 0x25c17fb7 0x25c1807b 0x25c0d7d1
>   0x25a258ef 0x2594fa6f 0x25377a0d 0x253733e5 0x2537326d 0x25372c51
>   0x25372a55 0x2536c92d 0x22457d95 0x22455453 0x2245585b 0x223a33c1
>   0x223a31d3 0x297780a9 0x259b17b1 0x102cb1 0x304c9aaf) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I checked the identifier several times so I can’t figure out what can lead to that crash.

Could anyone shed light on it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check spelling for the xib file's name. Are you sure it's lowercase?

Comment: Typo on question, sorry. In code all identifiers and names are correctly spelled.

Comment: This is not a solution, just advice. Instead of copy and pasting the identifier you should use a constant. `NSString* const myCustomCellReuseID = @"MyCustomCell" ` This gets you code completion, better refactoring, and avoids typing errors. Also, please get the stack trace or exception, that this crashes with.